# Blitz games managment

Tags: blitz

Here is the problem : when I have the time, i usually find the right move.
Meaning, in a longer time frame games (more than 10min) I'm doing better.
I feel like struggling with 5 min. games and I don't know how to improve.
I review my games usually using the computer but I haven't seen a big improvement, just a very small one.
To me it feels like I'm missing something that would elevate my level.
Any suggestions will be welcomed.
Thank you.

Comment: It would be very difficult, if not impossible, to help you without seeing the games. Please share a link for the games you have previously played so that we can highlight your weaknesses. Otherwise, you are likely to get general tips for blitz games.

Comment: I have an account in Chess.com witht he same nickname Quizhead.
I Can't link them all as there are dozens of them.

Answer (score 2):

Tactics play the most important part of winning blitz games. The tactical player has a better chance of winning a blitz game rather than a quiet, positional player (it is the other way round for classical chess). Next is intuition. To succeed as a blitz player, you must be able to figure out the next move without going into deep calculations (i.e. 'feel' the next move). For example, here is a game from your Chess.com account I analysed with a computer:

```
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]
[Event "Live Chess"]
[Site "Chess.com"]
[Date "2018.12.09"]
[Round "-"]
[White "quizhead (1238)"]
[Black "redhatkillers (1208)"]
[Result "0-1"]
[WhiteElo "?"]
[BlackElo "?"]
[Variant "Standard"]
[TimeControl "-"]
[ECO "A02"]
[Opening "Bird Opening"]

1. f4 g6 2. Nf3 Bg7 3. e4 e6 4. Be2 a6 5. d4 b5 6. O-O Ne7 7. c3 f5 8. e5 Bb7 9. Be3 Bh6 10. Nbd2 Nd5 11. Bf2 Bxf4 12. Bh4 Qc8 13. Bf2 Be3 14. Kh1 Bxf2 15. Rxf2 Qd8 16. Qc2 g5 17. Raf1 g4 18. Ne1 Ne3 19. Qd3 Nxf1 20. Bxf1 Qh4 21. Qe3 Nc6 22. Nd3 Na5 23. Nf4 Rg8 24. b4 Nc4 25. Nxc4 bxc4 26. Qg3 Qxg3 27. hxg3 h6 28. Bxc4 c6 29. Bb3 a5 30. a3 axb4 31. axb4 Ba6 32. c4 Ke7 33. Rf1 Rg5 34. Rd1 Rh8 35. d5 h5 36. dxc6 dxc6 37. Nd3 h4 38. Nc5 hxg3+ 39. Kg1 Bc8 40. b5 cxb5 41. cxb5 Rgh5 { Black wins. } 0-1
```

**10. Nbd2** is a normal move in an opening, but unfortunately not here. Your opponent has the massive d5 square for their knight. You should have paid attention to Nd5. It forks the bishop and the pawn, and you are forced to give up the pawn. 10. g3 would've saved the pawn, though that knight is still annoying.

**17. Raf1** allows a fork too. From the d5 square the knight is a serious threat. Usually when a knight is about to enter your territory, you must give it adequate attention.

**25. Nxc4** looks like it wins a pawm worsens your position. Your opponent didn't notice that 25... g3 wins your rook, and fortunately you had a chance to correct that by playing Qg3.

These are just some remarks. There is still much to learn, by playing more and more games and highlighting the positions where you blunder such tactics. It happens to us all. As it is said, the player to make the next to last mistake usually wins. We all do fall for such tactics, but one needs to minimize this to have a good chance at blitz.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I will add to my question : After the game I can see the mistakes clearly. I want to avoid them during the game.

Comment: You cannot avoid all mistakes, but only the most obvious ones. Nothing other than training and intuition can accomplish this in a blitz game.

Comment: " 10. f3 would've saved the pawn" - Didnt you mean g3 ?

Comment: Also, G3 is a bit risky ,the knight on f3 can easily pinned and captured without the pawn who protects him

Comment: @Isac yes I meant g3, sorry.